# Cron alternative with timeouts and second resolution

Tags: linux, freebsd, cron

Do you know an alternative to cron daemon that has second resolution, timeouts, and advanced system for error reporting? But it should be lightweight and should support different platforms(linux and BSD systems).

Answer (score 3):

[fcron](http://fcron.free.fr/doc/en/fcrontab.5.html) has second resolution for *repeats*

> The entries of commands which have to be run once every m minutes of fcron's execution (which is normally the same as m minutes of system's execution) are of the form
>
> `@options frequency command`
>
> where frequency is a time value of the form value*multiplier+value*multiplier+...+value-in-minutes as "12h02" or "3w2d5h1". The first means "12 hours and 2 minutes of fcron execution" while the second means "3 weeks, 2 days, 5 hours and 1 minute of fcron execution". The only valid multipliers are:

```
Table 2-1. Valid time multipliers

meaning:          multipliers:
months (4 weeks):   m
weeks (7 days): w
days (24 hours):    d
hours (60 minutes): h
seconds:            s
```

Comment: And what about timeouts?